# Deploy magento site on AWS

Tags: magento2, aws, deploy, deployment

I want to deploy a sample `magento` site on AWS. I need help to deploy site on AWS from scratch. Anyone can provide proper documentation for deployment of `magento` on AWS.

Answer (score 0):

if you need only to test something, you can pull this image to your account:

https://aws.amazon.com/marketplace/pp/B00NNZTA6Y?qid=1579692242591

> Up-to-date and secure image. Magento is a powerful open source
>   e-commerce platform. With easy customizations and rich features, it
>   allows retailers to grow their online businesses in a cost-effective
>   way.